# how to upload file in Android using MultipartEntityBuilder?

Tags: android, multipartform-data, boundary

I want to upload a file from Android to server using MultipartEntityBuilder after set Content-Type also it's not able to upload.

```
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();        
builder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

Log.d("Name", firstname+" "+lastname);

builder.addTextBody("firstName", firstname);
builder.addTextBody("lastName", lastname);

Log.d("ProfilePicturePath", picture);

if (picture.length()>0) {
    builder.addPart("picture", new FileBody(new File(picture)));
}

Log.d("Boundary", boundary);
Log.d("URL", url);

String credentials = Base64.encodeToString((username+":"+password).getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);

httpPost.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic "+credentials);
httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);

Log.d("BasicAuthorization", credentials);

httpPost.setEntity(builder.build());

HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
```

Please go through my code and suggest me some solution.

Comment: Any errors? What goes wrong exactly? Your server is in php? If so then post php script.

Comment: `Log.d("ProfilePicturePath", picture);`. Please tell what it logs.

Comment: ProfilePicturePath - /storage/sdcard0/abcd/IMG_20150601_152933_.JPG

Comment: hey thanks @greenapps so does it depends upon the server script so then i need to check with the backend guy.

Comment: `httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type",,,,,,,,` Try without.

Comment: means no Content-Type..

Comment: No. Only that you do not mess around whith the multipart. Now did you try?

Comment: httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary); like this...

Comment: can you tell me what will be the Content-Type ???

Comment: You were asked to completely remove that statement.

Comment: if i'll remove the Content-Type then it's giving 400 bad request..

Comment: Ok. Then ask the bacvkend guy how to post a file. Now is it php?

Comment: No it's not php some other language..

Comment: `other language` such comments do not quickly bring a solution i think.

Comment: You are setting a boundary but nowhere using it. Try without boundary. And ask those guy's. And add a scala tag to this post.

Comment: without boundary also i have tried, status code is coming 200 but it's not updating to the server.

Comment: Your code lacks reading the returned page. So you do not know what is send as response. Add it to your code and inspect it.

Answer (score 0):

You can update a file by using `FileBody`. Here is small example on it.

```
FileBody fileBody = new FileBody(file);
StringBody stringBody1 = new StringBody("Message 1", ContentType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
StringBody stringBody2 = new StringBody("Message 2", ContentType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
// 
MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
builder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
builder.addPart("upfile", fileBody);
builder.addPart("text1", stringBody1);
builder.addPart("text2", stringBody2);
HttpEntity entity = builder.build();
//
post.setEntity(entity);
```

You can get the content type  by using [getContentType](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/HttpEntity.html#getContentType())

```
entity.getContentType()
```

Comment: `You can update a file by using FileBody`. OP is already doing that.

Comment: hey thanks i have tried this but it's not uploading and also i got the content-type.